# How to parse array and stored values in variables

Tags: php, arrays

I written a php code with which I make an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Men's 100 metres

    [1] => Tom Burke

    [2] => Fritz Hofmann

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Alajos Szokoly

            [1] => Frank Lane

        )

)
```

I know that the value of elements of this array are always in the same position:

```
Position 0 --> the event sport
Position 1 --> who won gold medal
Position 2 --> who won silver medal
Position 3 --> who won bronze medal
```

It is possible that 2 or more athletes could win gold or 2 or more athletes could win silver. Above is only an example.

So I'd like to get this result:

```
$gender = Men
$event =  100 metres
$athlete = Tom Burke
$medal = Gold

Second loop:

$gender = Men
$event =  100 metres
$athlete = Fritz Hofmann
$medal = Silver

Third loop:
 first internal loop:

   $gender = Men
   $event =  100 metres
   $athlete = Alajos Szokoly
   $medal = Bronze

 second internal loop:

   $gender = Men
   $event =  100 metres
   $athlete = Frank Lane
   $medal = Bronze
```

How could I do?

Comment: If the array key is > 0, check to see if the array value is an array, then loop

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's currently blocking you? It seems like a simple `for` loop

Comment: And for `$gender` and `$event`, use `preg_match()` (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) on your index 0.

Comment: `extract()` may or may not become handy at some point, take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: I would propose you work with Objects or at least with named arrays. It will be way more easy to understand.

Comment: It would be more logical to store medal winner in array even if there's only one. e.g. [0 => 'Men's 100 metres', 1 => [0 => 'Tom Burke']]. And I agree with @inetphantom that you should use object or associative array in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While traversing, you just have to check if the value is array or not. If its, let it traverse then.

```
$a = array(
"Men's 100 metres",
"Tom Burke",
"Fritz Hofmann",
array("Alajos Szokoly", "Frank Lane"));

foreach( $a as $key => $value ){
if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        echo $k."\t=>\t".$v."\n";
    }
} else {
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the data structure to your needs like this:

```
// Sample data:
$events = [
  ["Men's 100 metres", "Tom Burke", "Fritz Hofmann", ["Alajos Szokoly", "Frank Lane"]],
  ["Men's 200 metres", ["John", "Mark"], "James", "Patrick"]
];

// Conversion:
$medals = ["gold", "silver", "bronze"];
foreach ($events as $row) {
    $gender = "";
    $event = array_shift($row);
    if (strpos($event, "'s ") > 0) {
        list($gender, $event) = explode("'s ", $event);
    }
    foreach ($row as $i => $athletes) {
        if (!is_array($athletes)) $athletes = [$athletes];
        foreach($athletes as $athlete) {
            $result[] = [
                "gender" => $gender,
                "event" => $event,
                "athlete" => $athlete,
                "medal" => $medals[$i]
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

After that you'll have the `$result` array, which looks like this:

```
[
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '100 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Tom Burke',
    'medal' => 'gold',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '100 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Fritz Hofmann',
    'medal' => 'silver',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '100 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Alajos Szokoly',
    'medal' => 'bronze',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '100 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Frank Lane',
    'medal' => 'bronze',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '200 metres',
    'athlete' => 'John',
    'medal' => 'gold',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '200 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Mark',
    'medal' => 'gold',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '200 metres',
    'athlete' => 'James',
    'medal' => 'silver',
  ],
  [
    'gender' => 'Men',
    'event' => '200 metres',
    'athlete' => 'Patrick',
    'medal' => 'bronze',
  ],
]
```

That will be easy to output.